# OpenVPN very slow speeds (<5Mbit). Both server and client is on 100Mbit connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have 100Mbit connection on both server and client.

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero, setup with PiHole and OpenVPN.

But I'm unable to get speeds faster than around 5Mbit. Is this a hardware limitation (Raspberry pi), or could the ISP's detect and throttle the VPN? I tried changing the server to TCP on port 443, but not sure if ISPs are still able to detect the VPN traffic?

The server ISP should be good (never experienced throttling).

I don't trust the client ISP, they have throttled various things before, and dont have very good routing. What's the best way to test a raw data transfer between the server/client, to see if maybe the problem is simply bad routing or something by the client ISP?

Edit: Meassured speeds from Speedtest.net:

Server: 99.5/98.9 (up/down)

Client: 79.3/89.7

Client when connected through VPN: 6.2/8.3

Edit2:
Client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote xxx 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_PRUDzjgaJqIn97DA name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
```

Comment: First step would be to eliminate the Pihole setup, then it would be to eliminate the ISP DNS, without knowing the performance is without those two highly suspect setups this question will be difficult to answer

Comment: Home connections are typically asymmetric and measured in upstream and downstream bandwidth. You’ve said you have 100Mbps connection. Those connections typically have 10 to 20 Mbps upstream. What are the results of a Speedtest.net on both ends? How are you measuring your VPN throughput? Without setting a standard to talk about we don’t know if there is an actual problem to solve.

Comment: It's fiber on both ends, so 100/100. I measure using Speedtest.net, but the experience is slow on normal websites also.

Comment: See edit in original post.

Comment: @JamesT Please post the client config, anonymizing any sensitive info

Comment: @JW0914 added config to post. Server config is default, except I changed to TCP port 443 (to avoid being blocked)

Comment: I think the Raspberry Pi is the bottleneck. It uses USB Wifi, and it only gets 17Mbit down and 10Mbit up. But I would think I would get a little faster VPN speeds?

Comment: @JamesT One of the issues is definitely your cipher, which was my initial hunch.  AES128 is currently uncrackable and will remain so for another decade or so.  TLS ciphers should be utilized, as their more efficient, resulting in higher throughput.   See this [client](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/Client.ovpn) and [server](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/OpenVPN-Server.conf) config as an example of tuned configs.  Also, x64 CPUs process SHA512 faster than SHA256.